# Driver Location Tracking in android N,O,P

Tags: android, location, driver, tracking

I have task to track driver location for a day or 2 days, so am getting last updated location from `FusedLocationProviderClient` and storing that data to `FireBase` `Realtime Database`. its working fine in `Marshmallow` but in N, O, P its dropping service because of android new policy like. No continues `background service`.

Previously I tried using service and `JobIntentService` but I both concepts am not able to get records continues in `android version >= N` because of Android Os kills `background service`.

```java
public class MyJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private static final String TAG = "MyJobIntentService";
    /**
     * Unique job ID for this service.
     */
    private static final int JOB_ID = 2;

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        showToast("Job Execution Started");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        int maxCount = intent.getIntExtra("maxCountValue", -1);
        /**
         * Suppose we want to print 1 to 1000 number with one-second interval, Each task will take time 1 sec, So here now sleeping thread for one second.
         */

        TimerTask repeatedTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ///    }
                Log.d("onStartCommand:","TrackingService111");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    startMyOwnForeground();
                else
                    buildNotification();
                loginToFirebase();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(repeatedTask, 30000, 30000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        showToast("Job Execution Finished");
    }


    // Helper for showing tests
    void showToast(final CharSequence text) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MyJobIntentService.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void buildNotification() {
        String stop = "stop";


        registerReceiver(stopReceiver, new IntentFilter(stop));
        PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Create the persistent notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Testing!!")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(broadcastIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tracking);
        startForeground(1, builder.build());
    }

    private void startMyOwnForeground() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
            String channelName = "My Background Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    //.setSmallIcon(AppSpecific.SMALL_ICON)
                    .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2, notification);

        }
    }
    protected BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "received stop broadcast");
            // Stop the service when the notification is tapped
            unregisterReceiver(stopReceiver);
            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    private void loginToFirebase() {
        // Authenticate with Firebase, and request location updates
        final String email = getString(R.string.firebase_email);
        final String password = getString(R.string.firebase_password);
         FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth success");
                            requestLocationUpdates();
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
                            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException) {
                    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                            .getCredential(email, password);


                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        request.setInterval(10000);
        request.setFastestInterval(50000);
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        final String path = getString(R.string.firebase_path) + "/" + getString(R.string.transport_id);
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Request location updates and when an update is
            // received, store the location in Firebase
            client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {



                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);

                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "location update " + location);
                        //  Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"location update " + location,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ref.setValue(location);
                    }
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use foreground service for that. Also note that doze mode will suspend your service. To prevent it you have to asquire wakelock

Comment: Thank you for your reply.i will try

Comment: Hi  Vladyslav, can you please refer me some link for foreground service with JobIntentService..

Comment: the most modern way to schedule tasks is `WorkManager`: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager